# Error: NG0900: Error trying to diff '[object Object]'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed in Angular 15

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, ngfor, angular15

The below mention code showing the data in the console but not showing in the page

`contactus.component.html`

```
<div class="section">
  <div class="container p-2">
    <div class="row pb-5">
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6" *ngFor="let query of contactUsQueryData">
        <div class="card ">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">{{query.Department}}</h5>
            <p class="card-text">{{query.Email}}</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

`contactus.component.ts`

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ContactusService } from '../../Service/contactus.service';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-contactus',
  templateUrl: './contactus.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./contactus.component.css']
})
export class ContactusComponent implements OnInit{
  contactUsQueryData:any[] =[];
  constructor(private _contactusqueryServices: ContactusService){}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this._contactusqueryServices.getcontactUsQuery().subscribe(data=>{
      this.contactUsQueryData=data;
      console.warn(data);
    });
  }
```

`contact.service.ts`

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';
import { QueryContact } from '../models/contactus';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ContactusService {

  private contactusquerypath='contactusqueries';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  getcontactUsQuery():Observable<QueryContact[]> {
    return this.http.get<QueryContact[]>('http://localhost:1337/api/contactusqueries');
  }
}
```

its showing as an error like below
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bVEJ5.png)

in the console the data is coming in an array format but in the page its not showing

Comment: Your response is not an array. But it is an object. You should extract the response with the `data` field.

Comment: @yong can you please help me to resolve the issues.

Comment: Replace `this.contactUsQueryData=data` with `this.contactUsQueryData=data.data` (as `getcontactUsQuery()` returns a wrapper object with a `data` property which contains the array data)

Answer (score 0):

From your screenshot, your response is an object but not array. You should extract the array from the `data` field. Note that, in each object, there is an `attributes` field which I believe you want to extract it.

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "attributes": {
        "Deptartment": "Dep 1",
        "EmailAddress": "abc@email.com"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "attributes": {
        "Deptartment": "Dep 2",
        "EmailAddress": "def@email.com"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

```
getcontactUsQuery(): Observable<QueryContact[]> {
  return this.http
    .get<any>('http://localhost:1337/api/contactusqueries');
    .pipe(
      map((x: any) => x.data.map((y: any) => y.attributes) as QueryContact[])
    );
}
```

Also, you need to revise your model/interface and view against the JSON response schema as currently those fields (name) are not matched.

```
export interface QueryContact {
  Deptartment: string;
  EmailAddress: string;
}
```

```
<h5 class="card-title">{{query.Deptartment}}</h5>
<p class="card-text">{{query.EmailAddress}}</p>
```

[Demo @ StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-nsuwhl?file=src%2Fcontactus.service.ts)